# Is their story inverse to Matanga based on illegitimate birth?

Tags: scripture, brahmins, varna, itihasa, chandala

From this story in the Mahabharata (https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826352.html) Matanga who was thought to be a Brahmin by his cruel acts and nature was deduced to be a Chandala by illegitimate birth. I am wondering if an inverse story is mentioned and a Chandala born illegitimately was a Brahmin and deduced in the same manner. If not what of other Varnas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar inverse story is found in **vana parva CCXIV & CCXV** :

> **vana parva CCXIV**
>
> *"The fowler replied, 'O good Brahmana, Brahmanas are worthy of all respect from me. Listen, O sinless one, **to this story of a previous
> existence of mine**. O son of an excellent Brahmana, **I was formerly
> a Brahmana, well-read in the Vedas, and an accomplished student of the
> Vedangas. Through my own fault I have been degraded to my present
> state**. A certain king, accomplished in the science of dhanurveda
> (science of archery), was my friend; and from his companionship, O
> Brahmana, I, too became skilled in archery; and one day the king, in
> company with his ministers and followed by his best warriors, went out
> on a hunting expedition. He killed a large number of deer near a
> hermitage. I, too, O good Brahmana, discharged a terrible arrow. And a
> rishi was wounded by that arrow with its head bent out. He fell down
> upon the ground, and screaming loudly said, 'I have harmed no one,
> what sinful man has done this?' And, my lord, taking him for a deer, I
> went up to him and found that he was pierced through the body by my
> arrow. On account of my wicked deed I was sorely grieved (in mind).
> And then I said to that rishi of severe ascetic merit, who was loudly
> crying, lying upon the ground, 'I have done this unwittingly, O
> rishi.' And also this I said to the muni: 'Do thou think it proper to
> pardon all this transgression.' But, O Brahmana, the rishi, lashing
> himself into a fury, said to me, **'Thou shalt be born as a cruel
> fowler in the Sudra class**."*
>
> **vana parva CCXV**
>
> *"The fowler continued, 'Thus cursed by that rishi, I sought to propitiate him with these words: 'Pardon me, O muni, I have done this
> wicked deed unwittingly. It behooves thee to pardon all that. Do thou,
> worshipful sir, soothe yourself.' The rishi replied, 'The curse that I
> have pronounced can never be falsified, this is certain. But from
> kindness towards thee, I shall do thee a favour. **Though born in the**
> **Sudra class thou shalt remain a pious man** and thou shalt undoubtedly
> honour thy parents; and by honouring them thou shalt attain great
> spiritual perfection; thou shalt also remember the events of thy past
> life and shalt go to heaven; and **on the expiation of this curse, thou
> shalt again become a Brahmana**. O best of men, thus, of old was I
> cursed by that rishi of severe power, and thus was he propitiated by
> me.*

Comment: This is a good example, but is their anything more inverse?

Comment: Need to find that. There is a story of vishvamitra cursing some of his sons to lose brahmana status

Comment: The more you give the merrier, thanks for being dedicated. I was looking for a story where a Chandala is thought to be of legitimate birth, but due to qualities is found out to be a Brahmina.